# Using functionals in Mathematica

Tags: function-construction, functional

I recently installed *Mathematica* and I wanted to define a functional in it. This is what I did:

```
autocorrelate[f_[t], τ_, T_] := Integrate[ f[t]*f[t+τ], {t, 0 , T}]/T
```

This was processed without a hitch.

I tried using it as on a sine function:

```
autocorrelate[Sin[t], τ, 2Pi]
```

and it gave me the output of

```
Cos[τ]/2
```

Which is right.

Then I defined a function:

```
a[t_]:= E^t
```

and when I used the command:

`autocorrelate[a[t],τ, 10]`

I get the output as `autocorrelate[E^t, τ, 10]`. Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I *know* this is a duplicate (a couple of times over), but I can't for the life of me find an example! In any case, one solution is to do `SetAttributes[autocorrelate, HoldFirst]`. Do that and try it again.

Comment: I'd also use `f_[[t_]` although the current specification is not wrong as long as all your functions are in terms of t.

Comment: small typo: I meant to write `f_[t_]`.

Comment: Hey, thanks. This was a duplicate. That was what I was looking for too.

Comment: @march: That didn't work. It gave me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `SetAttributes` then you can do

```
  autocorrelate[f_, t_, \[Tau]_, T_] := 
  Integrate[f[t]*f[t + \[Tau]], {t, 0, T}]/T
```

Then with `a[t_] := E^t` you get

```
 autocorrelate[a, t, \[Tau], 10]
(*1/20 E^\[Tau] (-1 + E^20)*)
```

For the `Sin` function we have

```
 autocorrelate[Sin, t, \[Tau], 2 Pi]
 (*Cos[\[Tau]]/2*)
```